# Post processing of pages crawled using nutch

Tags: solr, lucene, mapreduce, nutch

I have a set of pages crawled using nutch. And I understand that this crawled pages are saved as segments. I want to extract certain key values from this pages and feed it to solr as xml.

A sample situation is that I have crawled a shopping website with many product listings. I want to extract key infos like Name, Price, Specs of the product and ignore rest of the data. So that I may provide to solr some xml like 
qwerty123qwerty
This is so that using solr I should be able to do sorting of different product listings based on the price.

Now how this extraction part can be done? Does map reduce come anywhere in picture?

Answer (score 2):

Turning raw web pages into information is not a trivial task. One tool used for this job is Boilerpipe. However, it won't give you a solution on a plate.

If you are working on a fixed target, you might just write your own procedural code to find the data you need. If you need to find this sort of thing in arbitrary HTML, you are facing a very hard problem with no off-the-shelf solutions.

Comment: It is not really arbitrary HTML. The extraction part could actually be done with simple regex. I was thinking if there were any specific solution for parsing this segments created by nutch.

Comment: Nutch just grabs the text of whar comes back over http, no?

Comment: yes. But is seems to stored in some other format rather than html or txt format